# Enlargement of area and perimeter in a rotation body

Tags: integration, analysis, volume

Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous, differentiable function with $f \ge 0$. Rotate the graph of $f$ around the x-axis. Define this rotation body in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $A$ and the area in $\mathbb{R}^2$ between the x-axis and the graph of $f$ with $B$.

(a) Now enlarge $B$ around $(0,0)$ with factor $r >0$, so the new set is $rB:= \{r\cdot(x,y) : (x,y)\in B\}$. Ascertain the area and perimeter of $rB$!

(b) Enlarge $A$ around $(0,0,0)$ with factor $r>0$, so the new set is $rA:= \{r\cdot(x,y,z) : (x,y,z)\in A\}$. Ascertain volume and surface area of $rB$.

I haven't any idea.. unfortunately the concent doesn't fit to the lecture.. Any help and ideas?

Comment: What kind of an answer are you after? Is it enough to say "The perimeter of $rB$ is $r$ times the perimeter of $B$"? Or do you _have_ to write down the full expression $$r\left(1 + f(0) + f(1) + \int_0^1|f(x)|dx\right)$$ for the perimeter of $rB$?

Comment: No, i need a full expression of the perimeter $rB$, that's my problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what the problem is trying to say is that if the point $(x,f(x))\in B$, then $(rx,rf(x))\in rB$, so we can parameterize $rB$ as
$$\left(u,rf\left(\frac ur\right)\right)$$
For $u\in[0,r]$. Then the perimeter of the region bounded by $u=0$, $y=0$, $u=r$, and $y=rf\left(\frac ur\right)$ is
$$\begin{align}P(r)&=rf(0)+r+rf\left(\frac rr\right)+\int_0^r\sqrt{1+\left(\frac d{du}\left(rf\left(\frac ur\right)\right)\right)^2}du\\
&=rf(0)+r+rf(1)+\int_0^r\sqrt{1+\left(f^{\prime}\left(\frac ur\right)\right)^2}du\\
&=rf(0)+r+rf(1)+\int_0^1\sqrt{1+\left(f^{\prime}\left(x\right)\right)^2}r\,dx=rP(1)\end{align}$$
Where we have made the substitution $u=rx$. Also
$$A(r)=\int_0^rrf\left(\frac ur\right)du=\int_0^1rf(x)\cdot r\,dx=r^2A(1)$$
For the surface area of the solid of revolution we have
$$\begin{align}S(r)&=\pi(rf(0))^2+\pi\left(rf\left(\frac rr\right)\right)^2+\int_0^rrf\left(\frac ur\right)\sqrt{1+\left(\frac d{du}\left(rf\left(\frac ur\right)\right)\right)^2}du\\
&=\pi(rf(0))^2+\pi(rf(1))^2+\int_0^rrf\left(\frac ur\right)\sqrt{1+\left(f^{\prime}\left(\frac ur\right)\right)^2}du\\
&=\pi(rf(0))^2+\pi(rf(1))^2+\int_0^1rf\left(x\right)\sqrt{1+\left(f^{\prime}\left(x\right)\right)^2}r\,dx=r^2S(1)\end{align}$$
And its volume,
$$V(r)=\int_0^r\pi\left(rf\left(\frac ur\right)\right)^2du=\int_0^1\pi\left(rf(x)\right)^2\cdot r\,dx=r^3V(1)$$
So they are just trying to get you to show that blowing everything up by a factor of $r$ blows up the perimeter by $r$, areas by $r^2$, and the volume by $r^3$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
1) You substitute $u=rx$ right? But whats the reason $(u,rf(\frac{u}{r}) \in B$?
2) Can you explain this equation come about especially the added terms: $P(r)=rf(0)+r+rf(\frac{u}{r})$?

Comment: The first part came from blowing up $(x,y)=(x,f(x))$ to $(rx,ry)=(rx,rf(x))$. Then making the substitution $u=rx$, it means $x=\frac ur$ so now $$(rx,ry)=\left(r\left(\frac ur\right),rf\left(\frac ur\right)\right)$$ For the perimeter, $rf\left(\frac ur\right)$ was the obvious curved side on top, $rf(0)$ is the left side, $r$ is the bottom, and $rf(1)$ is the left side.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Last question about the $P(r)$. The left and right side are circles right? So the perimeter of the circles is $U_{c}=2\pi r \cdot f(0) + 2\pi r f(1)$. Why there isnt $2\pi$ in your equation? And i dont understand the $r$ for the bottom?

Comment: Part $(a)$ dealt with the perimeter and area of a $2$-dimensional figure whereas part $(b)$ asked about the surface area and volume of a solid of revolution. Thus in part $(a)$ the end-pieces are line segments from $(0,0)$ to $(0,rf(0))$ and from $(r,0)$ to $(r,rf(1))$ while in part $(b)$ the end-pieces are circles of radius $rf(0)$ and $rf(1)$. At least that's how I read the problem statement.